# Cannot give ACL permissions to perform network connections

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle12c

Using Oracle 12c database and Apex 19.1. I need ACL permissions to APEX_190100 user, to perform Google social sign in to our Apex applications.

I performed these scripts:

```
BEGIN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
host => '*',
ace => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect'),
principal_name => 'APEX_190100',
principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
/

BEGIN
DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.APPEND_HOST_ACE(
host => 'localhost',
ace => xs$ace_type(privilege_list => xs$name_list('connect'),
principal_name => 'APEX_190100',
principal_type => xs_acl.ptype_db));
END;
/
```

I got this error while performing Google sign in:

```
SID=62
USER=APEX_PUBLIC_USER
INSTANCE=1
Error: Error processing request.
- additional_info: Contact your application administrator.
- display_location: ON_ERROR_PAGE
- is_internal_error: true
- apex_error_code: APEX.UNHANDLED_ERROR
- ora_sqlcode: -29273
- ora_sqlerrm: ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 1035
ORA-28759: failure to open file
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1148
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190100.WWV_FLOW_WEB_SERVICES", line 934
```

So I executed the ACL permission scripts with SYSTEM service, and perfomed a HTTP request with PL/SQL, and I got this error:

```
ORA-29273: failure of the HTTP request
ORA-24247: network access denied by the access control list (ACL)
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need the "resolve" privilege.  Or you might need to add an ace with the schema owner as the principal.